# ActiveRecord - Find next user in group model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've four user models: `Zone`, `Product`, `User`, `Group`
I want to choose what `User`s can sell a `Product` in a `Zone`, this is what `Group` does, with a many to many relation to `User` and a foreign key to one `Product` and one `Zone`. So I have one group per pair Zone/Product. I will also need to set custom attributes on that many to many relation so I used `has_many :through Sell` (I was unable to find a better name to describe the relation between `Group` and `User`).
So I ended up having 5 models: `Zone`, `Product`, `User`, `Group`, `Sell`.

It works fine, but now I'd need to select the next user available in a `Group`.
I was thinking to exploit Sell.id to find the user assigned to the same group with an higher id, if not present choose the first one again (this allows me to create a ring chain).
It would be useful to have a `Group.next_user` method.

Unfortunatly I can't figure out how to do this, I'd need help to find the next user available in the group (or the 1st one if there are no more users).

Follows the code for models all the models:

```
################
# models/group.rb
################
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sells
  has_many :users, :through => :sells

  belongs_to :zone
  belongs_to :product
  attr_accessible :priority, :product_id, :user_ids, :zone_id
end

################
# models/zone.rb
################
class Zone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  has_many :cities
  has_many :groups

  attr_accessible :name, :location_id
  validates :location, :presence => true
end

################
# models/user.rb
################
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_calendar
  before_destroy :destroy_calendar
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :mall
  has_one :event_calendar

  has_many :sells
  has_many :groups, :through => :sells

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable, :registerable,
  # :recoverable, :rememberable,
  devise :database_authenticatable, :trackable,
         :validatable, :authentication_keys => [:username]

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :username, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :name,
                  :surname, :role, :location_id
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  ROLES = %w[Admin Agente Hostess HostessAdmin]

  validates_uniqueness_of :username, :case_sensitive => false
  validates :username, :presence => true
  validates_presence_of :role, :name, :surname, :location_id
  validates :location, :presence => true
    validates :role, :inclusion => { :in => ROLES, :message => "%{value} non è un ruolo valido." }

  def display_name
      "#{self.name} #{self.surname}"
  end

  def has_role?(role)
    # convert the role string to a sybmol
    self.role.downcase.gsub(/\s+/, "_").to_sym == role
  end

  private
  def create_calendar
    if self.has_role? :agente
      calendar = EventCalendar.new({:user_id => self.id})
      calendar.save()
    end
  end

  def destroy_calendar
    if self.has_role? :agente
      calendar = EventCalendar.find_by_user_id(self.id)
      calendar.destroy()
    end
  end

  def email_required?
    false
  end

  def email_changed?
    false
  end
end

################
# models/product.rb
################
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_groups
  before_destroy :destroy_groups
  attr_accessible :name

  def create_groups
    for zone in Zone.all
      group = Group.new({:zone_id => zone.id, :product_id => self.id})
      group.save()
    end
  end

  def destroy_groups
    for zone in Zone.all
      group = Group.find_by_product_id(self.id)
      group.destroy
    end
  end
end

################
# models/sell.rb
################
class Sell < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Can you give me some help to get this done? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I get this right then addd this to your User model

```
scope :next, lambda { |p| {:conditions => ["id > ?", p.id], :limit => 1, :order => "id"} }
```

and this to your group model

```
def self.next_user
  return User.first if Group.users.blank?
  next_user = User.next(Group.users.last).first
  return next_user || Group.users.first
end
```

This should do the trick. I didn't write test for this so you should test it :)